# Signal R related functions are not working in the app published in play store

Tags: react-native, google-play, signalr

I have used react native 0.59.3 and react-native-signal R 1.0.6 to create an app. Signal R is used for real time updates.
Normally it works fine but when i uploaded the app into play store, only the signal R related functions are not getting triggered.

If it is regarding versioning issue what are the correct versions should be used together. Or is their any other causes

Do i need to add any dependencies inside the buildgradle file.

Anyone experienced please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is so simple. Check the re connectivity of the hub listeners.